# how to make a mysql_query with a variable not defined in database

Tags: mysql

I have a C code which is doing mysql query. But now I want to update a particular column inside the program which I am not being able to do. Can anyone please help me.

```
conn = mysql_init(NULL);   // MySQL Database connection //
mysql_real_connect(conn, NULL, NULL, NULL, "bypass_new", 0, NULL, 0);
mysql_query(conn, "SELECT txnum, rxnum from data");
result = mysql_store_result(conn);
num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);
k = 0;      

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
{
  if(row[0])(p_info + k)->callingP   = row[0];
  if(row[1])(p_info + k)->calledP    = row[1];
  mysql_query(conn, "update data set flag_imei=1 where txnum=row[0]");
  k++;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following pseudo code idea it much faster and optimized than the one you mentioned :

```
 k = 0;      
 myIDsArray = array();

 while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
 {
   if(row[0])(p_info + k)->callingP   = row[0];
   if(row[1])(p_info + k)->calledP    = row[1];

   myIDsArray.addId(row[0]);

   k++;
 }

  myString = [myIDsArray joinByString:","];
  myQuery = "update data set flag_imei=1 where txnum in ( " . myString . " ) ";
  mysql_query(conn, myQuery);
```

Comment: This did not help me much, I want to know how to pass variables in mysql query in c.

Comment: i did not get question if you mean that please edit your question